# How to safely change username and hostname?

Tags: hostname, username

I installed a fresh `Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.3` today, but I just notice that I reversed the username and hostname during installation.

To illustrate this, when I open a terminal, the prompt looks like :

```
myhost@myname:~$
```

instead of

```
myname@myhost:~$
```

It is the unique user (so it is the normal admin).

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: If it's a fresh system, you may find more convenient to simply reinstall it with the right data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Changing the hostname

Change the hostname in the following two files:

- `/etc/hostname`
- `/etc/hosts`

(You'll need to use `sudo` to edit these files. Eg. `sudo nano /etc/hostname`)

## Changing the username

First, set a password for root:

```
sudo su
passwd root
```

Then **reboot the machine**.  When you see the login screen, switch to a virtual terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>.  Login with the username `root` and the password you set previously.

It's now safe to change the username using the following three steps:

1. Rename the user:

   ```
   usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
   ```
2. Change the name of the user directory and all daughter directories to match the new username and update the filepaths:

   ```
   mv /home/oldUsername* /home/newUsername*
   ```
3. Update the user database:

   ```
   usermod -d /home/newUsername* -m newUsername
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It Worked for me. :)

Comment: what does asterisk in step 2 mean?