# How to change the default Username on a KDE Plasma Login screen

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, login-screen, plasma

Whenever I start-up my desktop, or when it times out, I am presented with the "administrator" **username** on the login screen (please see example screenshot below). I then have to click on "Different User" to sign-in as my own user.

I would like the default to be my own username. How can I configure this on the KDE Plasma themed desktop?

[image]

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/659454/how-to-safely-change-username-and-hostname helps

Comment: Hi DK Bose - thank you for the link. I've had a look at this but its not really the answer I was looking for. Maybe I am wrong but I would have thought that it should be quite a straight-forward configuration item to tell the KDE Plasma Login to use "user-id-A" as the default rather than "user-id-B".

Comment: Found solution???

Comment: @Augusto sadly not... and I am no longer working on that platform these days (using Mac instead :)) - maybe someone else will be able to offer the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the System Settings there is an option for it:

[image]

See https://www.simplified.guide/kde/automatic-login for further details

Comment: Thank you @Freeman for the answer. Unfortunately I am no longer working in this environment - but this does look like the thing I was looking for back then. I hope your post can help another user and hopefully the up votes will help to confirm its helpfulness. Thanks again.